# sed: change word order and replace

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace;

```
randomtext{{XX icon}}
```

by

```
randomtext{{ref-XX}}
```

..in a file, where XX could be any sequence of 2 or 3 lowercase letters.

---

I attempted rearranging the word order with awk before replacing "icon" with "ref-" with sed;

```
awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

..but since there is no space before the first word nor after the second one, it messed up the curly brackets;

```
icon}} {{XX
```

---

What is the simplest way to achieve this using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed 's/{{\([a-z]\{2,3\}\)\sicon/{{ref-\1/'
```

This one liner uses the substitute command `s/PATTERN/REPLACE/`. `{{` matches two brackets. `\([a-z]\{2,3\}\)` captures the pattern that matches 2 or 3 lowercase letters. `\s` matches a white space. `icon` matches the literal string "icon". Then we replace the match, that is, `{{....icon` with the literal string `{{ref-` and the captured 2 or 3 letter word.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic version using hash tags (`#`) as regex delimiter:

```
sed 's#{{\([^ ]*\) [^}]*#{{ref-\1#'
```

- `{{` anchors the regex at the double open curly braces.
- `\([^ ]*\)` captures everything up until a space.
- `[^}]*` eats everything up until a closing curly brace.